# Java Stream Api INNER JOIN Two Lists

Tags: java, java-8

How to replace this code with using Java Stream Api?

```
for (Book book : Books.getAllBooks()) {
        for (SearchResult searchResult : searchResultList) {
          if (searchResult.getTableName().replace("attr_", "") .equals(book.getTableName())) {
            bookList.add(book);
          }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
List<Book> bookList = Books.getAllBooks().stream()
            .filter(e -> searchResultList.stream()
                         .anyMatch(f -> e.getTableName().equals(f.getTableName().replace("attr_", ""))))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 8):

I came from C# and missed that feature in Java 8 API, so I wrote my own.
With [streamjoin](https://github.com/simomat/streamjoin) you can write

```
Stream<Book> books = 
 join(Books.getAllBooks().stream())
 .withKey(Book::getTableName)
 .on(searchResultList.stream())
 .withKey(SearchResult::getTableName)
 .combine((book, searchResult) -> book)
 .asStream()
```

Answer (score 2):

Not *exactly* what you asked for, but here's another trick if you're using Guava:

```
List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>(Books.getAllBooks());
Lists.transform(bookList, Book::getTableName)
        .retainAll(Lists.transform(searchResultList, r -> r.getTableName().replace("attr_", ""));
```

Answer (score 2):

In my opinions, your example is a particular case of join operation, because your result set doesn't take any column of `SearchResult`. For most people going into this question like me, **the general join operation with Java Stream** is what they want. And here is my solution :

- step 1, flatMap with judging whether the result should be null or not
- step 2, filter the stream in step 1 by nonNull

It works fine, although it's not so elegant, which seems like u implement a join operation yourself--

The pseudocode may like :

```java
//init the two list
List l1 = ...;
List l2 = ...;

//join operation
res = l1.stream().flatMap(
    _item1 -> l2.stream().map(_item2 -> (_item1.join_key == _item2.join_key)?
         ([take the needed columns in item1 and item2]) : null
    )
).filter(Object::nonNull);
```